# How to pass maven command-line arguments to a inline Groovy script

Tags: maven, groovy, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/) to release some artifacts. During the `release:perform` goal I would like to run a inline Groovy script which use my SCM credentials to proceed some tasks.

This is a snippet of my `pom.xml`

```
...     
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <goals>
      clean
      deploy
      org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:execute
    </goals>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-cli</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>
           log.info "Username: ${project.properties.username} account"
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

I invoke Maven as follow

```
mvn -B release:prepare release:perform -Dusername=foo -Dpassword=bar
```

And I gete the following output:

```
Username: null account
```

I tried to have a look at the Official [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) page but it seems some snippets are missing...

Any idea?

---

**EDIT**

I finished by passing the credentials in the `goals` section

```
...     
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <goals>
      clean
      deploy
      org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:execute -Dusername=${username} -Dpassword=${password}
    </goals>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

The command line is till the same:
`mvn -B release:prepare release:perform -Dusername=foo -Dpassword=bar`

As said by [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) it seems like the release cycle Maven is forked. I'm not sure it pass all the command-line arguments to the forked process. So doings this is like I'm forcing the forward of the CLI arguments.

Comment: This must be something to do with some other configuration you have as it works fine for me when I use the same syntax as you've shown.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the [-Darguments=](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments) parameter of the maven-release-plugin, cause during the release cycle maven will be forked and that seemed to be the problem here.

Like this

```
mvn -B release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Dusername=foo -Dpassword=bar"
```

Take care on the quotes.